# How to create a task schedule calendar?

Tags: android, schedule, android-calendar

I need to create a schedule calendar like a schedule class. 
But i don't know how to start. 
How i can create the design with the hours and the task associate with a specific hour?

Anyone have a tutorial ou a document that help me to start with the project?

I know that is not a question about programming but if you can help me, i apreciate a lot.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [calendar-scheduler-android](http://code.google.com/p/calendar-scheduler-android/) project. This may provide a way to fulfill your requirement.